# Separating rolling papers, that have stuck together

Tags: smoking, adhesive

Occasionally tobacco rolling papers can get stuck together when the pack gets slightly damp/moist. I usually try slowly pulling them apart, but this results in the papers ripping 4 out of 5 times. Does anyone have a solution that is more reliable than just pulling them apart?

Comment: Giving up smoking is a great solution for this ;)

Comment: Question could also be applicable to other uses of rolling papers.  I use them to make paper cartridges for black powder revolvers.

Answer (score 6):

Dampening the adhesive part will help you separate them again, but you'll find that you're just using up more of the glue and the paper will be harder to stick.

Ideally, keep your rolling papers in your tobacco pouch / tin, as the tobacco will act as a natural desiccant keeping the excess moisture away from your papers.

Comment: yes，I agree @Andrew Williams's answer.Of course, to ensure that in a sealed environment, an estimated 2 days on the OK, not the effects of cut tobacco quality.